# Best RGBA video rendering for windows 10 please

Tags: transparency

I'm trying to render a transparent alpha as a video, what is the best settings for blender 3.1 . I use PNGs image sequence, but a video would be better for my working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EXR image sequence is probably the best option for rendering only alpha. It does not save any color transforms and it's lossless. Rendered image sequence is easier to fix if you have some problems with your animation and need to re-render parts.

If you want multiple channels like RGBA, EXR still works, but if you want to save color transforms from Blender and don't intend to do some sort of color grading separately, you might want to use another lossless format like TIFF for example or even PNG, but I would recommend sticking with image sequence. Video formats are better suited for final output of your animation and usually do not have features needed for editing/compositing like multiple channels or layers as well as higher bit depth.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah makes sense.